# Start timer on a button click and stop it with 10 button clicks

Tags: android, button, timer, counter

So far I have the button tap counter working and it stops at 10 taps. My only problem is the timer. Every time I press the button it resets the timer. I want the button to start the timer on the first click and stop the timer on the 10th click, but am stumped and do not know how exactly to code this. Anyone know how I can get this working?

Java code:

```
package com.example.thirtytapgametest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int mCount = 0;

private ImageButton startbutton;

private TextView timerValue;

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);      
    startbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {            
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

            mCount++;
            countTextView.setText("Taps: " + mCount);
            if(mCount == 10) {view.setEnabled(false);}
        }           
    });

}



private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                +String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                +String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
    };

}
```

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/thirty_tap_game_background">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="138dp"
    android:background="@drawable/test_play_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:text="@string/timerVal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:text="@string/countVal" 
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for you to resolve your problem. As 'timeSwapBuff. is unused, I've commented that line of code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        startbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) { 
                if (mCount ==0) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                }

                    mCount++;
                    countTextView.setText("Taps: " + mCount);
                    if(mCount == 10) {
                        view.setEnabled(false);

                        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                        }
            }           
        });

    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
            updatedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

           // updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    +String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    +String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

        };
    }
```

Comment: @user3689022 - Please vote-up my answer as well as the answer is useful to you by clicking on the 'up' button

Comment: I will definitely vote up your answer by clicking the up button, but right now I am not at a high enough reputation to do so. Also, I have one more question that you may be able to help me with. With my current code, I have been trying to set up an Alert Dialog to pop up when the 10th click is reached but it is not working and keeps showing an error in my code. Any idea how you would set up an Alert Dialog with a button to play the game again in my code? Thank You!

Comment: Thanks. Please post another question with your code and logcat what error is occurring such that I could help you for sure...If i'm not in worst case entire SO is here to support you in that way !